# Transform query to RoR ORM

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, orm

How could I do it using the ORM Ror.

```
SELECT T.* FROM tables T, businesses B 
       WHERE ( (T.business_id = B.id) AND (B.name LIKE 'Canary Code S.L.') 
       AND NOT EXISTS(  SELECT R.* 
                        FROM reserves R, reserve_intervals RI 
                        WHERE (R.reserve_date = '2014-05-12' AND RI.name LIKE 'TARDE')) );
```